# Load PHP code in PHP for delayed + parameterized execution?

Tags: php, templates, class

I have two PHP files:

> - template.php
> - template.html.php

The first is the class definition for Template. The second contains an actual HTML-based template, however with  PHP constructs (hence the .PHP extension). I'd call this a hybrid html/php file.

**Is it possible to create some function in the Template-class (`special_include_parse()`) which takes a:**

- **$path** (to a hybrid html/php file)
- **$model** (which is passed to the code in the hybrid html/php file so that it can be referenced using $this->getModel() or $model or whatever...)

**?**

---

**template.php**

```
class Template {
    function Parse($model) {
        //include('/var/www/template.html.php');
        //fopen('/var/www/template.html.php');
        $return = special_include_parse('/var/www/template.html.php', $model);
    }
}
```

**template.html.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title><? echo $this->getModel()->getTitle(); ?></title>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like you're practically reinventing the Fry templating system: http://fry.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um... why not just set $this (although I wouldn't call it that) and include/require the template.html.php considering it's basically PHP syntax? Basically:

```
class Template {
  function Parse($model) {
    ob_start();
    require '/var/www/template.html.php'; // I wouldn't use absolute paths
    $return = ob_get_clean();
  }
}
```

Personally though I think this is a prime example of making something more difficult than it is by introducing an unnecessary (in fact, counterproductive) object abstraction to something that's otherwise pretty straightforward:

```
$model = new MyModel(...);
require 'template.html.php';
```

and

```
<html>...
  <h3><?= $model->getStuff(); ?></h3>
```

I'm not sure why you're overcomplicating it or rather what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I have View classes (.php) which can have a linked template file (.html.php). At the end of a script getHtml() is called on the View class. At this point a Model should have been set on the View class. The Viewclass somehow needs to pass that model it's template, so the template can be parsed with values from the model. I think the output buffering is actually what I'm looking for. Do you think there is another, more efficient way of achieving what I want?

Comment: How are your views being called or referenced?